# Django and the moment of instance creation

Tags: django

I was a bit surprised by this bit of code:

```
class DeliveryItem(models.Model):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._original_product = self.product
    ...

    def save():
        print(self.product)
        print(self._original_product)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The purpose of this code was to see, whenever a change to the related product was made.
The output is as follows:

**On creation of a DeliveryItem instance with the name "unicorn"**

```
--> unicorn
--> unicorn
```

**On update of a DeliveryItem instance with the name "unicorn" to "voldemort"***

```
--> unicorn
--> voldemort
```

This confused me ... the expected behaviour would be:

**On creation of a DeliveryItem instance with the name "unicorn"**

```
--> None(!)
--> unicorn
```

**On update of a DeliveryItem instance with the name "unicorn" to "voldemort"***

```
--> unicorn
--> voldemort
```

**Why is the instance created before the `save()` method is executed?**

Comment: Calling `save()` just makes these values stored in database. The fact that particular field has a value does not mean it is stored in database. It is just an instance field's value but only when you call save on the instance it will be permanent.

Comment: I agree with everything you say. Yet I find it confusing that the fields do not seem to be set during updating the instance. I would assume updating an instance consists out of instantiating it with new field values and comparing it to the database representation afterwards. This does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: What does that mean? What is not the case? The fields *are* set during updating the instance; why do you think they aren't?